# How to convert string formula into javascript equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, regex, quadratic

I've input formulae string like:

```
y = 5.02x^2 + 2x + 10
```

and I want the output string to be like:

```
y = 5.02*pow(x,2) + 2*x +10
```

So far what I've tried is to match it as a quadratic equation:

```
import re
strn = input ("Enter formula :") 
x = re.sub(r'(-?\d+)x\^2 ([+-]\d+)x ([+-]\d+)','Do not know what to put here',strn)
print(x)
```

but i don't know how to replace like `^` sign with `pow(a,b)` or `5x` as `5*x`

Comment: Will your formula string be like this always? A Mathematical expression can have several such operators like that and there might be brackets as well.

Comment: @lkdhruw actually it can be of different types. there can be negative signs but no brackets. the coefficients will be always either fraction or integer

Comment: @anubhava I've added my code, what I've tried so far

Comment: Do you want to only look for `x` after a digit or it can be any other letter? It would be better if you add few more examples to make it clear.

Comment: only x. but it can be capital or small letter

Comment: grouping the before and after parts of the ^ would help. You need a lookahead, then encase all numerical or alphabetical together in one group, with the same after. Like ([1-0]+)^([1-0]+). Then put the groups as part of the replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If requirement is just to address `*` and `^` operators then this code may work for you:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '5.02x^2 + 2x + 10'
>>> print ( re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])\^(\d+)', r'pow(\1,\2)', re.sub(r'(\d)([a-zA-Z])', r'\1*\2', s)) )
5.02*pow(x,2) + 2*x + 10
```

We are using 2 `re.sub` calls here:

1. `re.sub(r'(\d)([a-zA-Z])', r'\1*\2', string)`: Inserts `*` between a letter and a digit. *Note that digit must come before a letter*
2. `re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])\^(\d+)', r'pow(\1,\2)', string)`: Converts `^` to `pow` function

If your requirements are more exhaustive than this then please update your question.